# What is the difference between the two circles in the rotation tool in Unity?

Tags: unity, rotation, editors, rotate

What is the difference between the two circles in the rotation tool in Unity?

In 2D rotation tool there are two circles which allow to rotate an object. And I can not conceive a difference between them. Could someone explain me what is the purpose of having both of them? It seems they both do the same.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at the widget in 3D, not only in 2D?

Comment: @DMGregory, your comment explains the purpose of the three circles: green, red and blue. Thank you for that. But what about the outer white circle?

Comment: Did you try using the yellow-white circle in the 3D view?

Comment: @DMGregory, oh. That helps. So, the white circle is for a rotation relative to the current scene view. Right?

Comment: Want to post an answer with the results of your observations?

Comment: @DMGregory, done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comments provided under the question I was able to grasp the idea of the circles. There are four circles. Three of them are used to rotate around x, y and z axis and the fourth is used to rotate relatively to the camera which is used during the scene management in editor.